# Cypher MERGE with two uniqueness constraints

Tags: merge, neo4j, cypher, unique-constraint

Suppose I specify two uniqueness constraints on a label `Person` in Cypher:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON Person
ASSERT name IS UNIQUE
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON Person
ASSERT id_number IS UNIQUE
```

If I run the following `MERGE` command

```
MERGE (p:Person {name:"Alice", id_number=153})
```

the behavior is:

- if there is a node with the `name` Alice **and** `id_number` 153, it is returned
- if there is a node with the `name` Alice **xor** `id_number` 153, there is an error because we cannot create a new node and maintain both uniqueness constraints
- if there is a node with neither the `name` Alice **nor** `id_number` 153, a new node is created with these properties.

I want to change the **xor** behavior so that we do

- if there is a node with the `name` Alice **or** `id_number` 153, it is returned
- if there is a node with neither the `name` Alice **nor** `id_number` 153, a new node is created with these properties.

Any idea how to achieve this in Cypher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What should happen if you have one node with the `name` Alice and another different node with the `id_number` 153? That's kind of the central philosophical problem with this schema. Setting that aside, your closest bet is going to be manually adapting `MERGE` logic like so:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.name = 'Alice' or p.id_number = 153
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps
WITH ps, CASE SIZE(ps) WHEN 0 THEN [True] ELSE [] END AS news
UNWIND news AS new
MERGE (q:Person {name: 'Alice', id_number:153})
WITH ps, COLLECT(q) AS qs
WITH COALESCE(HEAD(ps), HEAD(qs)) AS p
```

You may not actually need uniqueness constraints in your case; they are often used casually in place of regular indexes, but they are really only necessary if you have to worry about asynchronous writes (which, even then, can be managed other ways). Otherwise you just need to be disciplined in query writing so that you use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE` and don't `MERGE` patterns with unbound nodes that should be unique.